# MySQL command line client issue + error 2003

Tags: php, mysql, cmd

Initially, I was able to open MySQL command line client, and when I type the password, error 2003 will flash very quickly and auto close the client.

After looking online, I try some of the suggested solution using *cmd*. 
From the attach photo you can see that I try `mysqld -install` and try `net start mysql` commands but they don't work.

[image]

So I using the control panel to repair MySQL Server 5.7. Now I can't open MySQL command line client as it will auto close itself.

How do I rectify this issue? Does reinstalling the whole MySQL works?

**To sum up**:

1) I can't open MySQL command line client

2) Even if I could, the previous problem can't solve -> error 2003, then autoclose

**Why I need to fix this**:
- I want to import data from a .sql file, and I used to do that via MySQL command.

Comment: Of course you are sure there is no firewall blocking communication on the port you run mysql? (3306 by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless articles on fixing this problem. My solution to this is **reinstalling or reconfigure**.

Edit: Reconfigure the settings to default

Comment: That's not a solution. You simply revert the configuration to default values.

Answer (score 0):

Using the cmd go to mysql folder, there should be a subfolder called bin.

Now navigate to bin and run `mysql -u user -p password` where user is your user and password is your password, for example: `mysql -u root -p abc123`

EDIT
Oh, I didn't pay enough attention to your screenshot. You cannot even start the service?

EDIT2
Nevertheless you should be able to start it manually launching directly from mysql/bin folder.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ud8Sx.png

Comment: Hi, tried your method, the image shows the 2nd problem, error 2003

Comment: Now this looks like your service wasn't running or your firewall is blocking the connection. If the service is running it is most probably the firewall.

Comment: Hi, I checked my firewall settings, there is no MySQL. I could make it an exception, but I'm not very sure what's the path to choose. I know it should in bin, but not sure which file is the right one

Comment: If you have the possibility for the sake of testing just turn off your firewall and try it again. Make sure the service is running. Keep in mind it might make you vulnerable during those few seconds. You have no password for root?

Comment: I suppose you already went through the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-command-line.html ?

Comment: I tried the manual with the firewall off, but it don't work. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/D08NA.png

Comment: If you write mysqld.trace it is not recognized as you haven't add the mysql folder to your windows path. Since it is not the firewall and the service is installed you had to configure something wrong during the installation. Other than that I have no idea, too many things..